# best way to bring an informally or self-taught programmer up to specification

Tags: training

I am a manager/supervisor of one programmer who, although enthusiastic, willing and hard-working, is inefficient owing, I believe, to the fact that he is self-taught and has never undertaken formal training in software development.  His solutions are frequently non-standard and fragile and he makes mistakes about which I was warned as an undergraduate.  As he has a constructive attitude, I believe that this can be remedied by giving him some formal training at company expense and my manager is willing to approve this.

He is a full-time employed programmer in Australia.  What would be the best way to 'fill in' his knowledge?  Are there suitable courses on-line for example, or should we send him to a university for one day a week, assuming a suitable course is available?

The languages we use here are mainly Java and PHP but I want more general data-structures and software engineering course rather than how to program one specific language.

Comment: this sounds a bit inflammatory. Is it relevant **why** somebody is not up to the task?

Comment: Yes, because that will influence the solution.

Comment: i suggest you review some of these Q&As you should scan this search: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=self-taught and https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=under-performing

Comment: Sounds like he needs a boot camp.

Comment: The best ways to bring programmer like that up to speed is to have someone actively working with him and help him patch his holes. Do code review and consult his code and ideas in non threatening manner, if neeed in private without any reprecussions for revealing his inadequacies. If he is aware of the problem most of the stuff can be mitigated by slowly working him in and making sure he understands. In other words - make him a sidekick for someone who can teach and answer his questions. The pay off should be half a year down the line, where you can review how well it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My answer is based specifically on the one example of "deficient" code the OP provided in a comment to another answer:

> he will create globally-visible static objects (in Java) 'just in case' he wants to access them from somewhere else in the code, later

I agree that this is poor code for a professional Java programmer to produce.  However, I'm not sure that this is the result of the developer being self-taught, rather than just very inexperienced.  I base my statement on having managed many freshly graduated computer scientists whom would likely produce the same code, and on my own recollections of my university assignments (now long ago) which focused on the algorithm vs the implementation.

I bring this point up because I think some of the ideas that the OP mentioned aren't really relevant - I don't think an online/real-life university course will teach what this developer needs to learn.

As code of this style is the result of inexperience, the only way to improve it is by increasing that developer's experience level, by exposing him to code written by more experienced developers.  This can be accomplished by code review in both directions (having an experienced dev review his code, and have him review an experienced dev's code), reading through books designed especially for experienced programmers (e.g. "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch), and even attending certain training conferences (something like QCon - even if most of it will be too advanced for him, it will introduce him to the fact that there is a lot out there he knows nothing about and will hopefully encourage self-growth).

Comment: Thanks to both you and Pranav;  you both gave very helpful answers that opened my mind to other ways of improving the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I want to give answer to how to bring you team/team member upto specification.

First question is do you have any defined standard for calling good or bad? I saw many people call code bad even if it is working and is efficient since naming convention is not as per their thought which is even not defined as any standard. Do you have any Continuous integration tool in place? Any code analysis tool in place? Any unit testing & code coverage tool in place? Any security testing framework in place? If yes your code already be upto standard otherwise my suggestions are:

- make sure you have some coding standards defined which is followed by whole team
- make sure there is a CI(Continuous integration tool) is in place
- make sure CI has alteast one of the code-analysis tool like SonarQube, JsLint, CodeLint,Fxcop etc in CI pipeline
- make sure developer are raising pull request to be reviewed by others where code issues can be identified before merging to Development branch for all.
- If you are concerned about security make sure there is some code analysis for security
  and some defined guidelines like OWASP top 10 practices and add in CI pipeline

Formal training might help but still will not make anyone write code what the way you want. I also sometime write clumsy code when I am doing some POC/fesibility analysis and know that code will not be used in production. People tend to avoid standard till there is a quality check in place.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Good points, some of which I already had in the pipeline of process improvement projects.  I certainly wouldn't criticise someone for failing to conform to an unwritten naming convention but to give the most recent example of what I would call a deficiency, he will create globally-visible static objects (in Java) 'just in case' he wants to access them from somewhere else in the code, later;  whereas generally, in whatever language, one tries to minimise visibility.  It's not 'wrong' to do this but it can lead to higher maintenance costs later.

Comment: @Miguel: I don’t know your dev, but the problem with global objects in particular and minimizing visibility is that access modifiers are often described as security and OOP is described as classes make inheritance possible.  I don’t think these myths are due to self taught programmers and they overpower the truth which is that the less you have to know to work with the code the easier it is to do so. Public is evil, because you have to worry about knowing that method and what it does all over the place.  And classes concentrate data and behavior into something  smaller than “my application”.

Answer (score -1):

Have him read.

Start with Code Complete.

At the back of that book, there is a section titled "A Software Developer's Reading Plan" where the author has a whole list of books that are required at his company to progress to specific positions.

To get beyond "Introductory programmer level" you must read Code Complete as well as:

- Programming Pearls
- Conceptual Blockbusting
- Facts And Fallacies Of Software Engineering
- Software Project Survival Guide

I would recommend them in that order